# Ajax drupal dialog doesn't respect dialog-option

Tags: modal-dialogs

I have:

```
$options['attributes']['class'][] = 'use-ajax';
$options['attributes']['data-dialog-type'] = 'modal';
$options['attributes']['data-dialog-options'] = json_encode([
  'width' => 375,
]);

return [
  '#markup' => Link::createFromRoute(
    t('My link'),
    $route,
    [],
    $options
  )->toString()
];
```

which generates a link as expected:

```
<a href="/node/1" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:375}">My link</a>
```

However when the dialog opens, it always has 800px set as width, how do I get it to open at the width set in the json_encode call?

The opened dialog div looks like this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; height: auto; width: 800px; top: 310.133px; left: 683px; z-index: 101;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" aria-describedby="drupal-modal" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1">
```

Comment: Don't know if this is mandatory, but it might be the dialog options are ignored when you don't define `data-dialog-type`.

Comment: I've added the rendered markup to the question. The element does specify 800px, so I don't think the theme overrides this.

Comment: @4k4 I've tried adding a type, and updated the question accordingly. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: I've tested the code and you need the type, otherwise the modal doesn't open at all. Otherwise the code is OK, can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: That's really interesting, because the modal opened for me before as well. O_o
I'm probably doing something dumb, but I can't figure out what...

Comment: Switch to Bartik theme and test there.

Comment: Bartik is a good idea, unfortunately the menu rendering where I link to the modal from broke there, and I can't be bothered spending time to fix that. I'll probably try to step through the dialog renderer instead and see how it treats the input parameters.